# Conda updates packages that I don't use

Tags: python, conda

I noticed a strange behavior. I ran `conda update --all` in `base` environment and got the following output:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.8.3                |           py37_0         2.8 MB
    idna-2.9                   |             py_1          49 KB
    pycparser-2.20             |             py_0          92 KB
    tqdm-4.43.0                |             py_0          56 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         3.0 MB
```

I don't have `tqdm` package installed, though `conda` updates it. Why is this happening? When I run `conda list -n base` there is no package `tqdm`, neither in any other environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

conda depends on conda-package-handling

conda-package-handling depends on tqdm

if you don't think you have it installed, you need to look closer. `conda update --all` will try to update anything you have installed.

```
$ conda search conda=4.8.3=py37_0 --info
Loading channels: done
conda 4.8.3 py37_0
------------------
file name   : conda-4.8.3-py37_0.conda
name        : conda
version     : 4.8.3
build       : py37_0
build number: 0
size        : 2.8 MB
license     : BSD 3-Clause
subdir      : linux-ppc64le
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le/conda-4.8.3-py37_0.conda
md5         : 50d4443514e3e27b11228cee8aef3653
timestamp   : 2020-03-13 16:59:23 UTC
constraints :
  - conda-build >=3
  - conda-env >=2.6
  - cytoolz >=0.8.1
dependencies:
  - conda-package-handling >=1.3.0
  - pycosat >=0.6.3
  - pyopenssl >=16.2.0
  - python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0
  - requests >=2.18.4,<3
  - ruamel_yaml >=0.11.14,<0.16
  - setuptools >=31.0.1


$ conda search conda-package-handling=1.3.0=py37_0 --info
Loading channels: done
conda-package-handling 1.3.0 py37_0
-----------------------------------
file name   : conda-package-handling-1.3.0-py37_0.tar.bz2
name        : conda-package-handling
version     : 1.3.0
build       : py37_0
build number: 0
size        : 252 KB
license     : BSD-3-Clause
subdir      : linux-ppc64le
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le/conda-package-handling-1.3.0-py37_0.tar.bz2
md5         : 0bcb9ed3ca68eb7fa5d1c4a7ede55de1
timestamp   : 2019-06-10 18:58:25 UTC
dependencies:
  - libarchive >=3.3.3
  - python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0
  - python-libarchive-c
  - six
  - tqdm
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. But what exactly does command `conda list -n base` show? Just manually installed packages?

Comment: `conda list -n base` shows all packages that are installed in the base environment. I see tqdm listed. (among 62 packages)